# JPA + Hibernate + Inheritance

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I have a strange way to map my class. Currently the table is for example:

Table1
column:  name   ( for English )
column:  nameDE ( for German )  etc etc  ( Don't ask why, it is not my database :) ).
column:  status  ( common )

I was thinking something like:

Super class:  Table1  with:

```
@Column(name = "name" )
protected String name;

@Column(name = "status" )
protected String status;

....getters & setters etc
```

Child class Table1DE extends Table1:

```
@Column(name = "nameDE" )
public getName() {...}
```

This way I would use the parent object to get English, the child object to get German and then Use the parent Object on my rest of tasks as a common object. Hibernate/JPA causes an error since it tries to find a Discriminator column.

I only managed to make it work if I have a Parent class with all the fields
and the two children classes , one for Eng, one for De. The problem is that this way I need to copy all getters & Setters with their Column mappings in each child object ( even status or Id that are common. )

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why use inheritance? Why don't you simply map the table as an entity and get the value of the right field according to the language you want? I don't see any reason to use inheritance in such a case.

Comment: I want to print the "Parent" generic object into XML. So I want to have the same tag: "name" in both EN and DE xmls... It will be better to treat the same exactly object in all languages in my next tasks.

Comment: Then add a method returning an object with only the name in the right language and the common attributes to the entity, and marshal this object to XML for example.